# How to keep daily time recording/tracking in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, time-management

How do I keep daily time recording/tracking in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Track your time in Outlook using Journal](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA100343461033.aspx) ?

And see also [Tasks and Time Management in Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/melissamacbeth/archive/2006/10/09/Project-Server-Tasks-in-Outlook_3A00_-Part-1-.aspx), parts 1 and 2.